# Multiple Google Accounts - Adding Meet Up Events

Tags: google-calendar

I have three Google Accounts - my personal one and two I manage for two different clubs.  Whenever I export a Meet Up event to my Google Account, the event always goes to the wrong Google Calendar.  There's no way I can select which account it should go to.  Any suggestions?